# How to set a variable for the current OS session only

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

`setx` permanently modifies environment variables.
`set` only makes variables available during batch script duration.
Is there any way to set a variable in order to hold its value until the system is restarted?
E.g. in my batch file, I'm checking if the variable is set like this:

```
if %MYVAR% == 1 (
<block>
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
IF NOT EXIST q25244121.org GOTO done
:: reset to original
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (q25244121.org) DO (
 IF DEFINED %%a FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%p IN ('set %%a') DO (
  IF "%%a"=="%%p" IF "%%b" neq "%%q" SET "%%a=%%b"
 )
)
:: Delete if not originally defined
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%p IN ('set') DO (
 FINDSTR /L /i /c:"%%p=" q25244121.org >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "%%p="
)

:done
:: Record current settings
set>q25244121.org

EXIT /b
```

This may work for you. You would need to change the `SET` instructions hown in CAPS to `SETX`. The tempfile would no doubt also need to be placed in a file where the username is part of the name you'd use.

If you were to include this batch in your startup directory, then it should restore the last-saved environment variables' values.

So, on first logon, the current variables' values are stored. On subsequent logons, the environment would be restored to those last stored, regardless of whether a `setx` had been executed.

You would however need to change procedures. This will restore to a known state. If you actually wanted to `setx` a value or install some software which adds new environment-variable values or changes existing ones (`PATH` would be favourite here) then you'd need to run this routine first, make the changes, delete the save file and re-run this routine. Awkward, I'll admit - but it's a way to do it.

Oh - and remember to `set` your variable after having `setx` it. You could even write a `setxX` batch to `setx` then `set` (or vice-versa) the required variable.

Comment: Excuse me. I am afraid I don't understand how this method could differentiate between cmd.exe sessions _of the current OS session_ and sessions of a posterior OS session (after the user logoff or the system restarts). I understand this method may differentiate _the first_ cmd.exe session from posterior sessions, but this is not the point that the OP requested.

Comment: @Aacini : probably you've missed the key point, that the `SET` commands in upper-case should become `SETX`. When this routine is run for the very first time, the file records the then-current settings. Any `SETX` in any `cmd` session that follows will change the value for future `cmd` settings - until the next login, when tis routine runs again. It detects the differences applied by any `SETX` in the previous OS session and `SETX`s them back to the condition in the file, as originally recorded so `cmd` sessions within the new OS session (once this startup batch has finished) are clean.

Comment: Actually, if this routine is `CALL`ed as posted, without changing the `SET`s to `SETX`s, then it will act within that particular `CMD` session to restore the original environment, which may also be useful.

Comment: Ok. I got it. The key point in your solution is that the Batch file **MUST be copied to the startup directory** of each user. I think this point is not clearly stated in your answer...

Answer (score 2):

You may do that via a Batch-JScript hybrid script that use JScript's WshShell.Environment method. The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156595.aspx) specify that there are four types of environments: System, User, Volatile and Process, and that Volatile type "Applies to current logon session and is not saved between logoffs and restarts", that is exactly what you want:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Define a persistent variable for the current OS session only via JScript
Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" MYVAR "This is the value"
goto :EOF

@end

var colEnvVars = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Volatile");
colEnvVars(WScript.Arguments(0)) = WScript.Arguments(1);
```

You must save previous code in a .bat file and execute it as any Batch file. Note that the variable defined this way is *not* available in *the current* cmd.exe window, but only in future cmd.exe windows opened in the same OS session.

Tested on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a much simpler (and obviously less hacky) way than the JScript method, but it put us in the right direction with the volatile environment manipulation.

Simply use the `reg` command to manipulate the volatile environment in the registry :

```
reg add "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /v "%MYVAR%" /d "%MYVALUE%" /f
```

`reg add` both can create and update the value.

`\f` bypasses the overwrite confirmation.

Setting an empty data with `\d ""` is equivalent to deleting the global variable. You won't see it in the shell with `set`, but you can still see it being empty in the registry.

Here is a reference: https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html